# Context-free grammar for $ \{a^lb^n c^m |l, n, m ∈ \mathcal{N}^+, l \geq \min(n,m)\}$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I know that $L = \{a^lb^n c^m |l, n, m ∈ \mathcal{N}^+, (l ≥ n) ∨ (l ≥ m)\}$ is a context-free language, because I know the context-free grammar, i.e.

$$
S \rightarrow AbZ \mid XBc \\
A \rightarrow aAb \mid X \\
B \rightarrow aBc \mid Y \\
X \rightarrow aX \mid a \\
Y \rightarrow bY \mid b \\
Z \rightarrow cZ \mid c
$$

I have a bit of difficulties understanding this construction. Can you explain step-by-step how it has been created? The rules?

Comment: Instead of trying to understanding an existing grammar, I suggest you try to create a grammar yourself from scratch (without looking at that one) and see where it takes you!

Answer (score 1):

Let us start by noticing that $X \to a^+$, $Y \to b^+$, $Z \to c^+$. Furthermore, $A \to a^n X b^n$ and $B \to a^m Y c^m$. Therefore $S$ generates words of the following two forms:
$$
a^na^+b^nbc^+ \\
a^+a^mb^+c^mc
$$
You take it from here.

Comment: You have modified my question with $S \rightarrow AbZ \mid XBc$. Are you sure this is correction? I had $S \rightarrow aAbZ \mid XBc$

Comment: Check out my answer and see for yourself.

Comment: I do understand what would do $A \rightarrow aAb \mid X$, $B \rightarrow aBc \mid Y$, 
$X \rightarrow aX \mid a$, $Y \rightarrow bY \mid b$ and $Z \rightarrow cZ \mid c$, but I have a bit of difficulties understanding what would do $S \rightarrow AbZ \mid XBc$. Could you add a bit more details?

Comment: You’ll have to work out some of it on your own.

Comment: Ok, but this is precisely why I asked the question. The other rules seems to be obvious for me, but not the $S \rightarrow AbZ \mid XBc$. It might help if you could develop a bit more.

Comment: I suggest spending more time on it.

Comment: I did, but nothing came up